# Difference between WD LPVT and BPVT

Tags: hard-drive

I am planning to buy new internal hard drive.

Can any one tell me the difference between Western Digital's **LPVT and BPVT model ?**

From my [search I found LPVT](http://www.flipkart.com/wd-blue-500-gb-laptop-internal-hard-drive-wd5000bpvt/p/itmdnymt3kzmzqxg) is having faster access time, more shock proof and durable, single platter and less noise than BPVT. What is the technical difference?

Comment: sorry for mistake.. Q updated.. its LPVT

Comment: From my search i found LPVT is having faster access time,more shock proof and durable,Single platter,Less noise than BPVT. What is the  technical difference ?

Comment: Power consumption of up to 1.4W is lower compared to other WD Scorpio Blue 2.5" drives (BPVT-series)

Comment: What do you mean by technical difference?

Comment: why its access time is faster than BPVT series? What are the factors for it?

Comment: This isn't possible to answer... there are many reasons why this could be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I could find, the LPVT series is optimized for Ultrabooks, namely it has:

- less power consumption (<=1.4W)
- less vibration
- quieter in general
- a little higher shock tolerance (~400Gs)
- aggressive spindown
- ultra fast spin-up times (~1.25s)

So this series is designed to compete SSDs with its nearly-as-high performance but much larger storage capacity.

Hope I could help you a little, I used this [news announcement](http://www.xbitlabs.com/news/storage/display/20120411161118_WD_Ships_Scorpio_Blue_Hard_Drives_for_Ultrabooks.html) and this [forum thread](http://www.silentpcreview.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=64340) as reference.